# Word for someone who's doing a commission task

Tags: single-word-requests

I am working on a commission board system, where users can post commission requests (they are named "clients"), and other users can come and apply for a commission.

Once they are hired by the client, they become the ??? of the commission.

As a non-native english speaker I thought maybe something like "commissioner" but it means something entirely different from what i've seen.

Comment: _employee_ perhaps but there must be a better word.

Comment: contractor seems to be accurate indeed :)

Comment: You perhaps should clarify what you mean by "commission".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Supplier

The person or organisation selected for the commission becomes the chosen *supplier* of the commission.

Here are some examples from the [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/supplier):

The extranet will link the company with its customers and *suppliers*.

We're suing our *suppliers* for failing to fulfil their contract.